# When checked don't unchecked (this) but other(s) checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

When a checkbox is checked, and I click on his checkbox, I won't uncheck the checkbox but another one ....

An example :

If I check the checkbox 1, checkbox 1 is checked;
If I check the checkbox 2, checkbox 1 and 2 is checked;
If I check the checkbox 3, checkbox 1, 2 and 3 is checked;

Then, for example, when checkbox 3 is checked, I click on checkbox 2, I only want to uncheck the checkbox 3 (not 1 and 2).

Here is my starting code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1" class="toggle" />
<input type="checkbox" id="2" class="toggle" onclick="document.getElementById('1').checked = this.checked;" />
<input type="checkbox" id="3" class="toggle" onclick="document.getElementById('1').checked = this.checked = false;document.getElementById('2').checked = this.checked = false;"/>
```

How can I possibly do that ?

Comment: Post your code here too, at least for future reference.

Comment: is it requirement or you are getting issue in implementing ? post whatg you tried

Comment: I wonder what might be the reason for creating such a useability nightmare.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/f2xU9/

Comment: If you really want a nightmare, use radios instead

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

### HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" class="chk"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" class="chk"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk3" class="chk"/>
```

### JQUERY:

```
$('.chk').change(function(){

if(this.id === "chk3")
    $(".chk").prop("checked",this.checked);
if(this.id === "chk2")
{
    $(".chk").prop("checked",!this.checked);
    $("#chk3").prop("checked",!this.checked);
}

})
```

### FIDDLE:

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/f2xU9/)

---

Comment: @user3694393: Are you saying no jQuery?

Comment: @user3694393 you added jquery tag so I asnwered with jquery

Comment: No, I will use jQuery don't worry, I think checkbox is too complicated for what I want. See this : http://codepen.io/casimirp/full/tucqE/ that's what I want to be done. If I want to click on one card, I just need to uncheck the card ahead